# Conflicting suggestions on Coc.nvim with Prettier and ESLint

Tags: plugin-coc, eslint

I am working in a team and none are using `Vim`. Most are use VS Code, and things are working fine for them.

However, I have this problem:

```
ticket.additionalNocs.forEach((additionalNoc) => nocs.push(additionalNoc));
```

If I remove the parens around `(additionalNoc)` , then run `:Prettier`, the parens get added back!

Our project has a `.prettierrc.js` and a `.eslintrc.js`. For everyone else in the team, the parens do not get added back. There should be no parens, yet for me, Prettier re-adds them.

I did `CocInstall coc-prettier coc-eslint`.

What am I missing? I do not want to mess with the config files, or add anything in the `package.json` file for the project, since like I said, I'm the only one facing this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to disable prettier for `javascript`

In vim `:CocConfig` (this opens `coc-setting.json`)

Add this line to the config file (don't forget trailing comma if needed:

```
"prettier.disableLanguages": ["javascript"]
```

Answer (score 1):

The canonical way to deal with this problem is to [disable ESLint's formatting rules](https://prettier.io/docs/en/integrating-with-linters.html), because linting and formatting are two different concepts and one tool should not handle both. (Well, that's a matter of opinion, but certainly two tools should not both be handling one of them).

Prettier provides [an eslint plugin](https://github.com/prettier/eslint-config-prettier) to do this for you. Install `eslint-config-prettier` and then add "prettier" to the end of your `extends` array in your eslintrc file.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!